# Adding template to existing React Application

Tags: css, reactjs, templates

I have a medium experience in developing applications with React, and up to study and experience I have always used very basic layouts, creating components and styling with a .css file

Currently I want to start using the various react templates that I find online, such as:

`"Connect Plus React Free Admin Template"` etc.

This is the first time I try to integrate a template into an existing application.
So I tried to copy from the template what I needed and then bring it back to my application.
Then update `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`.
Unfortunately, then starting the app with npm start it broke and did not start anymore.

Do you have any tips, advice or guides on how to do this?

Comment: can you pls post the error been thrown

Comment: Hi, when i try to run the server with `npm start` in the VSCode terminal i can see the message "Server is starting...", this for 20/25 seconds.
Not any message are shown and i return on the terminal

Comment: have you done npm i 'template name' ; if yes delete node_modules & package-lock ; and re-install

Comment: Thank you! No I have not installed the react template, so, if I have not misunderstood, starting from the working react application and without the template.
Do I launch `npm i template-name`, which installs the template for me without having to download or clone it from git?
Once this is done, the template is then integrated with the existing application?

Comment: yes, when you do npm i 'template' this means in your node_modules that template dependencies are present and now whenever you host your app; it will download it from global repo referencing your package.json; you dont have to download or clone